# PostgreSQL - Periodically copying data from one database to another

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up an architecture with 2 databases, say **preview** and **live**, that have the exact same schemas. The use case is that edits can be made to the **preview** database and then pushed to the **live** database after they are vetted and approved. The production application would read from the **live** database.

What would be the most appropriate way to push all data from the preview database to the live database *without* bringing the live database down? Ideally the copy from preview to live would be an atomic transaction.

I've worked with this type of setup in MSSQL, but I'm fairly new to Postgres. So I'm open to hearing other ways to architect this (with Schemas perhaps?).

**EDIT:** The main reason to use separate databases is that I may need more than 1 target database (not just a single "live" database). I also may need to switch target databases on the fly without altering the source database schema.

Comment: Why use two databases? It is quite easy and efficient to do it on a single database.

Comment: In PG you can make an operation "atomic" (from the perspective of other users) by wrapping all the statements in a single transaction - the MVCC model.

Comment: There are a number of reasons to use separate databases - the preview and live databases may have different network and security requirements (firewall, etc) and/or need to be hosted on different machines. Another reason is that this architecture easily allows for multiple targets (not just live) without needing to add additional tables.

Comment: The only justification for different databases is a simpler schema. Otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: Simpler schema and the ability to add or change targets without altering the source database schema are the primary reasons I'm considering separate databases. But I'd be happy to hear if there are other alternatives that allow for this flexibility. I edited the question to add this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a "hot standby".  This would be a separate instance of Postgresql, possibly on the same server but usually not, which is a near-real-time replica of the primary server.

In broad strokes, this is done by shipping the binary transaction logs from the primary server to the backup server, and then "replaying" them there.  The exact mechanism for transmitting the logs may vary depending on your requirements.

Fortunately, the docs on this are excellent:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/warm-standby.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hot-standby.html